# How to set the image position relatively

Tags: flutter, dart

It is Flutter Layout basic question.

So far, I put a few images use `Row`.

However I want to do is putting image at 'right bottom' and 'left bottom'.

How can I accomplish this by Flutter layout system?

```
Row(
  children: [
    Image.asset('images/pic1.png',
      height:50,
      left:50, // this member doesnt exist.
      bottom:10// this member doesnt exist.
    ),
    Image.asset('images/pic2.png',
      height:50
      right:50,// this member doesnt exist.
      bottom:10,// this member doesnt exist.
    )
  ]
),
```

Comment: Have you tried [Align](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2E7yl3MwMk)?

Comment: Can you draw an example mockup?

Comment: use stack and positioned, these are the best way

Comment: Thank you I tried Align and it works. I am a newbie for Flutter though, I think I should remember the every layout at first.

Comment: I will try `positioned` as well for next challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Align`. For example, for bottom right, you can do like this:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
  child: YourWidget(),
)
```

Be aware that `Align` fills all the space it can get so you might want to constrain it within a `SizedBox` or `Container`!

[Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Alignment-class.html)'s everything you need to know about the `Alignment` class, which is what you pass to the `alignment` parameter of `Align` constructor.